# How to replace a link regarding to a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace, href

In my site I have one div like this

```
<div class="yjme_item_in yjmeitem29">
```

inside this div there is a link and I would like to replace the href of it, introducing www.google.com.

Any ideas ?

I have tried this with no luck

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("yjmeitem29")[0];
a.setAttribute("href", "www.google.es");
```

Comment: do you know why my code is not working ?

Comment: You're setting the href of the div.

Comment: oohhh you're right, thanks. So how should I set the href of the a tag which is inside this div ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a.childNodes[0].setAttribute("href", "www.google.es");
```

Comment: Word of caution, using `childNodes` in situations like this can fail quite unexpectedly (unexpected by some), if there is any whitespace between the parent element’s and the child’s opening tag.